# Close a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to close a Fragment after some event.
How to I simply replace the fragment with the original FrameLayout

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, new Fragment());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

I tried the code above and it does not work.

Comment: Here in this code, you are replacing a fragment. What you want to do is to go back to the previous fragment when this fragment is closed?

Comment: `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();` for closing the current fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a fragment:

```
FragmentTransition.remove(Fragment frag)
```

And all its view will removed from the container.